# why ember.js use transitionToRoute enter controller's init() function afte this enter Route's setupController?

Tags: ember.js

```
  this.transitionToRoute('myProjectDetail',pid);
```

after do this enter myProjectDetailController's init() function;

after this enter myProjectDetailRoute's setupController function;

why ?

Answer (score 0):

init is part of Ember's internal CoreObject and is fired when an instance of almost anything is created.  Generallyit isn't part of the recommended workflow, but if you do use be careful.

NOTE: If you do override `init` for a framework class like `Ember.View` or
    `Ember.ArrayController`, be sure to call `this._super()` in your
    `init` declaration! If you don't, Ember may not have an opportunity to
    do important setup work, and you'll see strange behavior in your
    application.

setupController is called every time the context(underlying model) for a route changes.